# Problematic when creating grid based on mobile first

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I just create grid based on mobile first (old style, not using flex). When I try my result, the width of element when on mobile is not work, it overwrite width from min-width: 768px. Here is the image

[image]

I've tested it on other element, and it's not have problem. Check out this image

[image]

why it's have different result, I'm using same css. Please help me :)

Comment: do not edit questions to invalidate existing answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have missed meta tag in head tag which specifically tells browser to take media queries css :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
```